# Signing my last commit won't reflect on GitHub

Tags: git, github, gpg-signature

I'm trying to sign my last commit by running the following steps:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~1
git commit --amend --no-edit -S
git push --force-with-lease origin my-branch
```

When I'm running `git log --show-signature` I can see that my commit is signed but it's not getting reflected in my branch. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Have you added your gpg/pgp key to your account on github?

Comment: Yes, I have. I usually sign my commits just forgot to sign this one